# How do i dynamically setContent for Tab from Preference Activity?

Tags: android, static, tabs, android-tabhost, preferenceactivity

I am noob to android development and i want to setContent dynamically for a particular tab.  During onCreate i set content as such:

```
    specs2 = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs2.setIndicator("NEWS",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.news));
```

However, I am having no luck switching the content from a PreferenceActivity. Here is my code:

```
 SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String selectednewsfeed = getPrefs.getString("list", "1");
    if(selectednewsfeed.contentEquals("1")){
        try{
            MyActivity.newsfeed.loadUrl("http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoldMoneyGoldResearch");
            MyActivity.specs2.setContent(R.id.tab5);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

I have no issues changing the content within MyActivity, it's just trying to accomplish this from PreferenceActivity that is the issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).  This allows you to receive information from the launched activity back in the activity which launched.

Quick example, to launch your PreferenceActivity:

```
// in MainActivity
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class), 0);
```

Then inside your PreferenceActivity, set some data to return to MainActivity:

```
// in PreferenceActivity
Intent returnData = new Intent();
returnData.putExtra("com.your.package.name.DATA", R.id.tab5);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnData);
finish();
```

Back inside MainActivity, override onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch(requestCode){
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            int tabResource = data.getIntExtra("com.you.package.name.DATA", -1);
            specs2.setContent(tabResource);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```